# How I can trigger a Cloud Run Job or Cloud Function after a Cloud Run Job finishes all its tasks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have a `Cloud Scheduler` that triggers a `Cloud Run Job` to run and parallelize the payload into 3 tasks using the `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` environment variable.

I would like to trigger another `Cloud Run Job` or `Cloud Function` after the previous `Cloud Run Job` finishes all the 3 tasks. I looked up in the Google documentation, but I could not find any reference in order to accomplish this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the most efficient (IMO) is to use Cloud Workflows with the [Cloud Task connectors](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/namespaces.jobs/run). The connector run the task and wait for completion. And then you can continue the workflow with different tasks that you want to execute.

[Cloud Workflows also support parallel execution](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/parallel-steps)

Another idea could be to use [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs) to catch the audit logs that mention the end of the job processing. But I prefer the first solution.